# INSERT data from SELECT query with UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query below,

```
WITH muhammed AS(
    SELECT * FROM acct_db2016.dbo.acct_tran WHERE trc_acno='12008001'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM acct_db.dbo.acct_tran WHERE trc_acno='12008001')
SELECT * FROM muhammed
```

I want to insert like below given

```
INSERT INTO acct_db2016.dbo.acct_tran SELECT * FROM muhammed
```

How to do that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Use a view instead of cte.

Comment: i am using sql server

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH muhammed AS(
    SELECT * FROM acct_db2016.dbo.acct_tran WHERE trc_acno='12008001'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM acct_db.dbo.acct_tran WHERE trc_acno='12008001'
)

INSERT INTO acct_db2016.dbo.acct_tran -- <-- put the insert at this line

SELECT * FROM muhammed -- <-- Why you are inserting duplicate data from the first table?
```

Comment: i have created new data based on the year 2016 database has only two entries what i meant is i want carried forward the data from 2015 to 2016

Comment: When i execute your query it shows this error ( An explicit value for the identity column in table 'acct_db2016.dbo.acct_tran' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.)